# Jasper report with dynamic number of subreports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to print a Class report by using Jasper.
MainReprt - Class/Divion Details
Subreport/subreports - Scorecard of each students.

My date Looks like below. Let's say we have two students Emy and Paul.

Student Name : Emy
Subject : Maths
Mark : 85

Student Name : Emy
Subject : Physics
Mark : 75

Student Name : Paul
Subject : Maths
Mark : 86

Student Name : Paul
Subject : Physics
Mark : 56

This data will be in a List scoreCardList.

How can I show two different Subreport for two students(That is dynamic depends on the number of students).

I need something like.

EMY

Subject : Mark

Paul

Subject : Mark

Please help me to create a report like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not even need 1 subreport, just a flat datasouce structure then group on Student Name. As is the question is broad (we need to do all the stuff) , if you like to narrow it down post some jrxml that you have tried. We need to know exactly how your datasource is and what output you need,

Comment: Thanks Petter..Its Working for me Grouping...Cheers.

Comment: I'm happy that grouping did the trick, I have suggested a duplicate on how to group, consider to accept to help out the community (there is nothing wrong with duplicates, give more entry points), Cheers.